# Changing text of input field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

## Objective

- In my if-else statement when a `.player` has the class
  `picked.is-inactive` the text of the input field **should be blank, but right now it's the name of last clicked player**.
- Right now, when a player is selected all 20 input fields have their
  text changed to the player last clicked. **However, the name of the
  first player with `picked.is-active` should be put into the first
  input field `#p1` and so on until all 20 players have been selected and the 20 input fields are filled.**

### scripts.js

```
// Every time a player is clicked, note the name of the player
$(".player").on("click", function(){

    // Get the name of that player, only if picked.is-active
    // Put the text of that player into the appropriate input field

    if ($(this).find("picked.is-active")) {
        var playerName = $(this).find(".player__name").html();
        $("input").val(playerName);
        console.log(playerName);
    } else {
        $("input").val("")
    }
});
```

### index.html (Form)

```
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="p1"  id="p1" required>
        <input type="text" name="p2"  id="p2" required>
        <input type="text" name="p3"  id="p3" required>
        <input type="text" name="p4"  id="p4" required>
        <input type="text" name="p5"  id="p5" required>
        <input type="text" name="p6"  id="p6" required>
        <input type="text" name="p7"  id="p7" required>
        <input type="text" name="p8"  id="p8" required>
        <input type="text" name="p9"  id="p9" required>
        <input type="text" name="p10" id="p10" required>
        <input type="text" name="p11" id="p11" required>
        <input type="text" name="p12" id="p12" required>
        <input type="text" name="p13" id="p13" required>
        <input type="text" name="p14" id="p14" required>
        <input type="text" name="p15" id="p15" required>
        <input type="text" name="p16" id="p16" required>
        <input type="text" name="p17" id="p17" required>
        <input type="text" name="p18" id="p18" required>
        <input type="text" name="p19" id="p19" required>
        <input type="text" name="p20" id="p20" required>
        <button type="submit">
            Submit your vote
        </button>
```

### index.html (Player)

```
<div class="player player--goalie year--1970">
                    <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
                        <p class="tooltip__name">Glen Hanlon</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Brandon, Man.</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1974-1977</p>
                        <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
                            <div class="stats__group stats--games">
                                <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
                                <p class="stats__number--games">172</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
                                <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">4.22</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">3.99</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">3.09</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
                                <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.892</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.891</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.906</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
                                <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">0</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">4</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">4</p>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
                    </div> <!-- tooltip -->
                    <div class="player__headshot player--hanlon">
                        <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="player__name" value="Glen Hanlon">Glen Hanlon</p>
                    <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell what specific textbox should update.

```
// Every time a player is clicked, note the name of the player
$(".player").on("click", function(){
    var playerNames = [];
    $("input:text").each(function(i, t) { playerNames.push(t.value) });

    if ($(this).find("picked.is-active")) {
        var playerName = $(this).find(".player__name").html();
        var index = playerNames.indexOf(playerName);

        if(index == -1) // add player
            $("input:text:eq(" + playerNames.indexOf("") + ")").val(playerName);
        else // remove player
            $("input:text:eq(" + index + ")").val("");           
    } else {
        $("input").val("");
    }
});
```

**Explanation**

on each click, getting all text box values into an arry `playerNames` using `$.each` loop

then check the active (or clicked) `playerName` already exists in the `playerNames` array or not.

if not exists (i.e `index == -1`) then add it to **next empty textbox**

`playerNames.indexOf("")` brings the index of next empty textbox

else remove it from the textbox where it exists.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: This is still filling in all 20 input fields, instead of a single one. Thoughts?

Comment: oh!.. i forgot to break the loop when done.. `return false;` updated the answer.

Comment: Very close. The only problem now is that clicking the same player a second time does not remove it from that input, but adds the same player to the next input. Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Awesome. If you could explain the logic behind how you got to your answer that would be amazing. It works like a charm.